# How can I change the phase of UIColor patternImage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uicolor, cashapelayer

I'm using the very convenient `UIColor(patternImage:)` to create some `CAShapeLayer`s with tiled patterns in an iOS 10 app with Xcode 8.2. Tiling always starts at the origin of the view, which can be inconvenient if you want it to start somewhere else. To illustrate, here's a screenshot from the simulator (code below):

[image: Tiling problem]

The `CAShapeLayer` on the left starts at (0,0), so everything is fine. The one on the right is at (110,50), so it's split in the middle. Here's the code:

```
let firstBox = CAShapeLayer()
firstBox.fillColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "test-image")!).cgColor
view.layer.addSublayer(firstBox)
firstBox.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)).cgPath

let secondBox = CAShapeLayer()
secondBox.fillColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "test-image")!).cgColor
view.layer.addSublayer(secondBox)
secondBox.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 110, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)).cgPath
```

I want to adjust the phase of the pattern for the right `CAShapeLayer` so that both tiles show a full face. Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621933-init) for UIColor(patternImage:) helpfully refers to a function for this purpose:

> To change the phase, make the color the current color and then use the
>   [setPatternPhase(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455334-setpatternphase) function to change the phase.

Sounds simple! But I'm having a hard time implementing it. I'm not really sure what "make the color the current color" means. I tried getting the current context and calling `setPatternPhase` on it, both before and after assigning the fill color to the layer:

```
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setPatternPhase(CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
```

No noticeable effect. I tried subclassing the containing `UIView` and setting the phase in its `drawRect:` method, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808484/149097). But `drawRect:` doesn't exist in Swift, so I tried both `draw(_ rect:)` and `draw(_ layer:, in:)`. Both functions get called, but there's no noticeable effect.

```
class PatternView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setPatternPhase(CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
        super.draw(rect)
    }
    override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        ctx.setPatternPhase(CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
        super.draw(layer, in: ctx)
    }
}
```

At Dave Weston's suggestion, I used `UIImage`'s `.set()` to set the current stroke and fill for the current context before calling `setPatternPhase`. Unfortunately the output is unaffected. Here's the code I tried:

```
let secondBoxColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "test-image")!)
secondBoxColor.set()
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setPatternPhase(CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

let secondBox = CAShapeLayer()
secondBox.fillColor = secondBoxColor.cgColor
view.layer.addSublayer(secondBox)
secondBox.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 110, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)).cgPath
```

**How can I shift the phase of the pattern that gets drawn into a `CAShapeLayer`?**

Answer (score 0):

To make your pattern the current color, you should call the  `set()` instance method on the `UIColor` instance that contains your pattern. This configures the color as the current stroke and fill color for the current context.

Then, according to Apple's docs, `setPatternPhase` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using `set()` before `setPatternPhase()`, but it doesn't make a difference in the output. I edited my question to include the new code (at the end). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to solve this problem, but I thought I'd share the workaround I'm using in case it's useful to anyone.

As far as I can tell, `CAShapeLayer` does its rendering in a secret, hidden place, and ignores the normal `display()` and `draw()` functions that `CALayerDelegate`s are supposed to use. As a result, you never have access to the `CGContext` it's using to render, so there's no way to call `setPatternPhase()`.

My specific use case for `setPatternPhase()` was to have the pattern line up with the top-left of the CAShapeLayer it's drawn in, so I found an alternate way to do that. **It does not allow you to set an arbitrary phase.**

What I did instead is create a new `CALayer` subclass called `CAPatternLayer`that takes a `UIImage` to tile and a `CGPath` to fill. It delegates to a `CALayerDelegate` class called `CAPatternLayerDelegate`, which provides a `draw(layer: in ctx:)` function. When a draw is requested, the delegate creates a temporary `UIImageView`, fills it with the tiled image, then renders it to the `CALayer`'s context.

A neat side-effect of this is that you can use a `UIImage` with cap insets, which allows 9-slice scaling with the center slice tiled.

Here's the code for `PatternLayer` and `PatternLayerDelegate`:

```
class CAPatternLayer: CALayer {
    var image: UIImage?
    var path: CGPath? {
        didSet {
            if let path = self.path {
                self.frame = path.boundingBoxOfPath
                // shift the path to 0,0 since you built position into the frame
                var translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -path.boundingBoxOfPath.origin.x, y: -path.boundingBoxOfPath.origin.y)
                let shiftedPath = path.copy(using: &translation)
                // use the shifted version
                self.path = shiftedPath
                self.maskLayer.path = shiftedPath
            }
        }
    }
    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.delegate = CAPatternLayerDelegate.sharedInstance
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.mask = self.maskLayer
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    convenience init(path: CGPath, image: UIImage) {
        self.init()
        defer {
            self.image = image
            self.path = path
        }
    }
}

class CAPatternLayerDelegate: NSObject, CALayerDelegate {
    static let sharedInstance = CAPatternLayerDelegate()
    func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        // cast layer to a CAPatternLayer so you can access properties
        if let layer = layer as? CAPatternLayer, let image = layer.image, let path = layer.path {
            // create a UIImageView to display the image, then render it to the context
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            // if a path bounding box was set, use it, otherwise draw over the whole layer
            imageView.bounds = path.boundingBoxOfPath
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.layer.render(in: ctx)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example in use:

```
// create a path to fill
let myMaskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 25, width: 200, height: 100))
// pull the image and set it up as a resizeableImage with cap insets
let patternImage = UIImage(named: "ground")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16), resizingMode: .tile)
// create the CAPatternLayer and add it to the view
let myPatternLayer = CAPatternLayer(path: myMaskPath.cgPath, image: patternImage)
view.layer.addSublayer(myPatternLayer)
```

Output:

[image: 9-slice tiled pattern]